# How to open putty from webpage like html or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, linux, jsp, putty

I would need to open putty terminal from browser. 
initially I got answer as to change the registry setting to do it. But my client don't want to change registry changes.

After so many search in google I got the answer, using shellinabox you can install in Linux and configure to open via browser the terminal to login the Linux box.
 I just want edit my question which will be useful for others.
Thanks
Shanmugam

Comment: Webpage cannot run an arbitrary code on the client, unless it is provisioned somehow in advance. That would be a terrible security flaw.

Comment: *"Registry changes not accepting by client"* – Why exactly is the client not accepting registry changes?

Comment: ok understand, its client informed to explore without changing the registry need to open the putty, Ok I will inform as discussed here to client, Thanks for response all.

Answer (score 1):

For obvious security reasons, your browser cannot start another executable when a link is clicked.

Comment: is there any other way to open putty terminal from web page?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible what are you asking for, the only way is to use this technique and associate a custom "protocol" to a given executable:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/change-default-protocol-association/b5948b21-b25a-4f08-9336-a97d8b4e731e

But it *modifies the registry*

Comment: While actually the only reasonable solution, that's explicitly, what OP does not want.

Comment: So should I change the answer in something like, "it is not possible, the only way is..."?

Comment: That would make sense - But, PuTTY cannot  handle URLs anyway. So this link is not enough to open PuTTY.

Comment: Hi All , After long time searching I find one way below , which is shellinabox.. But after installed when I try to open using the browser its no opening , any one have experienced as such?

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/shell-in-a-box-a-web-based-ssh-terminal-to-access-remote-linux-servers/